# I am trying to Grep a command to find a string of command in a txt file, then write a script to count the lines in each file

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Here is my script below to automate it but i continue to get errors by the then, else, and fi areas where they are highlighted in red

```
#!/bin/bash
grep $1 $2
rc=$?
if[[$rc!=0]]
then
echo "specified string $1 not present in $2"
else
echo "specified string $1 is present in the file $2"
fi
# number of lines of in a file
wc -l | $2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Below is an better visual on the left side is my list of text to grep from and my right side is my script. I would love your advice with detail

[image]

Comment: To check a number of lines, you may use `wc -l < $2`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Definitely run it through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net). It points out all your missing spaces. If you install `syntastic` and `shellcheck` on your distro, you'll get that advice straight in Vim

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are required in the `if` command:

```
if [[ $rc != 0 ]]
```

You can also combine this with `grep`:

```
if grep "$1" "$2"
then
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the basic syntax down. What's wrong is that bash is really finicky about spaces between each of the sections of the if statement. You can't run everything together the way you've done. You also don't need the extra [ ] around the if statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep $1 $2
rc=$?

if [ $rc != 0 ]
then
  echo "specified string $1 not present in $2"
else
  echo "specified string $1 is present in the file $2"
fi

# number of lines of in a file
wc -l $2 | awk '{print $1}'
```

You also had an extra | in the last line.

Comment: You may not *need* the extra `[]`'s, but I highly recommend you continue to use those.